# How to use aggregate for group by in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection that contains documents with below schema.

**Schema**

```
{
    "categoryId": "1234",
    "sellerId": "2323",
    "productId": "121",
    "rating": 1
},
{
    "categoryId": "1235",
    "sellerId": "2323",
    "productId": "122",
    "rating": -1
},
{
    "categoryId": "1234",
    "sellerId": "2323",
    "productId": "123",
    "rating": -1
},
{
    "categoryId": "1235",
    "sellerId": "2323",
    "productId": "124",
    "rating": 1
},
{
    "categoryId": "1234",
    "sellerId": "2323",
    "productId": "125",
    "rating": 1
},
{
    "categoryId": "1234",
    "sellerId": "2325",
    "productId": "125",
    "rating": 1
}
```

The rating can have values `1` or `-1`. I want to find all documents grouped by `categoryId` and sum of the ratings. 
Example Result:

```
{categoryId: 1234, positiveRatingCount: 2, negativeRatingCount: 1}
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
ratingsCollection.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {sellerId: "2323" }
    },
    {

        $group: {
            _id: "$categoryId",
            count: { $sum: "rating" }

        }
    }
);
```

I get the following result. I am able to group by category but not able to figure out to get count of positive and negative ratings.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1234",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": "1235",
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) with the conditions([**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)) where the `rating` is [**`$gt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) or [**`$lt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) then **0**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "sellerId": "2323" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$categoryId",
    "positiveRatingCount": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$gt": [ "$rating", 0 ] }, "$rating", 0 ] }
    },
    "negativeRatingCount": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$lt": [ "$rating", 0 ] }, "$rating", 0 ] }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aKi7IQMiEiw)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1235",
    "negativeRatingCount": -1,
    "positiveRatingCount": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "negativeRatingCount": -2,
    "positiveRatingCount": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.